# java.io.EOFException when running a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm trying to run a complex PostgreSQL query on JetBrains DataGrip IDE. Expected rows => 164 with roughly 15 columns. Query initiated successfully but it errors out after a 10-15 seconds with `java.io.EOFException`.

```
Client OS => Windows 7
Backend DB => Postgres 9.4
Backend OS => Ubunti Linux 15
Client Java version => 1.8
```

EDIT:
Query involves a function with "RAISE NOTICE" statements in order to debug the code. Query runs OK if I turn off "RAISE NOTICE" statements in the function.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact Jetbrains' support, they're usually pretty good..

Comment: Same error on my end. Just randomly starts and appears to be on certain tables... I can select from any other table, no problem. weird